# nuxt 3 multi select with tailwind

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css, nuxtjs3

Hi I am trying to create a multi select input, I am working with nuxt 3 and Tailwind.
The problem I'm having is that I need to be able to add more options to what already exists in addition to the options that are displayed.

Here is the example of how to do it

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-ekbrgo)

But I need that for example if you select all elements of the select and add more, the container div will not expand with the content.

I have come up with two possible solutions number one is to limit the number of elements that are displayed selected and display a text that says "and X more" and the other option is to display a text that only says "X selected elements".